# How import GraphQLLocatedError and except it

Tags: python, graphene-python, graphene-django, graphql-python

i want to import `GraphQLLocatedError` and except it like this.

```
from graphql.error.located_error import GraphQLLocatedError

try:
    try code
except GraphQLLocatedError:
    except code
```

but it doesn't work..
please help me.